# What time does the boat hit the storm????

Tags: trigonometry

[Work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGzbY.jpg)A boat is travelling on a path bearing 330 degrees at a speed of 150km/h. The boat is 2700 km away from destination. A storm warning is issued on 2:15pm. The storm is 250km west of the boat, travelling north at a speed of 68.37km/h. What time does the storm hit the boat? I tried solving it using trigonometry and got answers that don't make sense. The storm is taking 6 hrs approx. to travel the intersecting distance but the boat is only taking 3hrs. Please solve if possible.

Comment: "boat is only taking 3hrs"  How on earth is 3 hrs * 150 = 2700?  The boat takes a *LOT* longer than three hours.

Comment: Draw a right triangle, with one leg going north south and another east west and the third a hypotenuse with angle of 330.  hypotenuse is 150 km/hr, the n/s is hypot x sin 330 km/hr and e/w is hypot x cos 330.  So when is hypot x cos 330 = 68.37 x t + 250?

Comment: The boat is taking more than *15* hours.  It's almost taking 20 hours.  It'd have to be traveling and 900 km/ to make it in 3 hours.  That's as fast as a jet plane.

Comment: You see the boat isn't travelling the full 2700km. It's interrupted by the storm somewhere in the middle. When a right angle triangle is drawn, the storm travels 433 km approx. to intersect with the boats path. The boat(hypotenuse) travels 500km. And the angle I am using is 60degrees as a right angle triangle can only ever have angles less than 90. Correct me if I make wrong please.

Comment: 330 is bearing clockwise from origin. To draw the triangles angle, 360-330=30. 90-30=60.

Comment: I commented with a request to show your work, then saw you put some work in a comment. It is much preferable to use the "edit" link below the question to add these details to the question itself.

Comment: As your calculations show, a second boat starting from the given point traveling at the given speed can never catch the first boat, because there is only one place the boat boats can meet (at a vertex of the triangle) and the second boat takes too long to get there. But storms are much, much larger than boats. Look for a description of the shape and size of the storm relative to that point "270 km west" and then maybe we can see when the storm and the boat will meet.

Comment: @DavidK I have added an image of my work. If u could explain what I did wrong it would be helpful. Thanks! Also this is from a movie on hurricanes. I believe it was 3 hurricanes coming together to form a giant one if that helps.

Comment: If this is relevant to a real-life story, maybe you have copied the wrong speed for the boat. 150 km/hour is about 81 knots; a cigarette boat might go that fast on calm water, but I wonder if there are any boats that can go that fast over ocean swells without getting wrecked. If the boat was a fishing trawler, 15 to 25 km/hour is a more reasonable top speed, 40 if it was built to be very fast.

Comment: In any case, your work is correct given the assumptions you made, and I don't see how to improve those assumptions without getting more information about the problem you are actually supposed to be solving. You may need to read the question more carefully or ask an instructor to clarify it.